# Two OnClickListeners with same effect (boilerplate)

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app I have situation like this:

```kotlin
videoImage.setOnClickListener {
    menuClickListener?.videoListClicked()
}
    
videoText.setOnClickListener {
    menuClickListener?.videoListClicked()
}
```

Both my listeners have the same effect and I consider this boilerplate code. This situation occurs relatively often, so I would like to know the MOST ELEGANT AND BEST solution for these situations.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions to this, the most elegant really being a matter of opinion. However I think these two are the most concise.

### Declaring a single `OnClickListener`

You could declare an `OnClickListener` that you use for both cases, so something like this:

```
val listener: (View) -> Unit = { ... }

videoImage.setOnClickListener(listener)
videoText.setOnClickListener(listener)
```

### Using a function

You could redirect the clicks to a different function:

```
videoImage.setOnClickListener { sharedClickFunction() }
videoText.setOnClickListener { sharedClickFunction() }
```

---

If you had more than a few views, you could also put them in an array and iterate through, but this seems a bit excessive. Something like this:

```
arrayOf(videoImage, videoText).forEach {

    it.setOnClickListener { ... }
}
```

Comment: don't mean to be rude but I have to say that I am not impressed. That still looks ugly to and boilerplatish to me. (nothing against you, I will upvote your answer)

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd like it to look? Even in more theoretical pseudocode? I just don't see how you could possibly make it more concise, you have to declare the behaviour somewhere, and you have to bind it somewhere so surely this is as concise as possible?

Comment: Kratos You provided a question with click listeners, @HenryTwist  has provided you with the two solutions for your question. That being said there are more ways to handle clicks than using click listeners, I think what you are looking for is ViewBinding or potentially Data binding.

Comment: For example I could put both Views that I will put clickListeners on in the same layout or Viewgroup and put one click listener on that view group.
But these are solutions in xml not in code. Ok I understand what you are saying. If no one gives the better answer till the next day, I will accept this on. Everything fine, no worries ;)

Comment: I see, the only similar code solution I can think of is to put them in an array and iterate through, but I think that's a bit overkill! Regardless, probably more efficient than introducing an extra `ViewGroup`, but I'd be interested to see if anyone else has any other in-code solutions!